# Importing DataFrames - no such file or directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a csv file as a dataframe into a Jupyter notebook.

```
rest_relation = pd.read_csv('store_id_relation.csv', delimiter=',')
```

But I get this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'store_id_relation.csv'
```

The store_id_relation.csv is definitely in the data folder, and I have tried adding data\ to the file location but I get the same error. Whats going wrong here?

[image]

Comment: did you try `rest_relation = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'store_id_relation.csv'), delimiter=',')`

Comment: @Mogi Providing the full path is the solution, but the code you offer will find exactly the same (wrong) path that the OP got. The solution is to find the correct path, which means it has to be either specified as absolute, or specified as relative to some known directory (not cwd, if you don't know what cwd is).

Comment: you're right, if it didn't work for him this is what I would suggest.. it's easy the get lost in path with python the way he uses it, this is why I wanted to let him try find the correct path on his own because it isn't necessarily `/Data/..`. we don't know the working directory he is using. this is why @rajsuryan answer is good

Answer (score 10):

Using the filename only works if the file is located in the current working directory. You can check the current working directory using `os.getcwd()`.

```
import os
current_directory = os.getcwd()
print(current_directory)
```

One way you can make your code work is to change the working directory to the one where the file is located.

```
os.chdir("Path to wherever your file is located")
```

Or you can substitute the filename with the full path to the file. The full path would look something like `C:\Users\Documents\store_id_relation.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to pass the full path whenever possible

By default, read_csv looks for the file in the current working directory

Provide the full path to the read_csv function

However in your case , `data` and `Data` are different , and file paths are case sensitive

You can try the below path to fetch the file and convert it into a dataframe

```
rest_relation = pd.read_csv('Data\\store_id_relation.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case where you don't want to change your read_csv()'s parameter, just make sure you are in a correct path of directory which your .csv file is in. Otherwise you can change your directory into there and then run the python file or simply change read_csv()'s parameter.